# Android NestedScrollView is behind NavigationBar

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have very complex `ConstraintLayout` inside `NestedScrollView`. I have to set `margin` 72dp to see the button on the bottom. I haven't tested, but I think that on devices without `NavigationBar` like `Xiaomi` or `Meizu` I will find big gap of 72dp on the bottom of this screen.

Interesting fact, but if I change behavior from `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` to `bottom_sheet_behavior` my margins shown as expected and I can see that big gap, but scrolling behavior is for sure is unexpected, so I cannot go with this approach. Here's some of my code:

My theme:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/grapefruit</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/grapefruit</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/lightgrey</item>
    <item name="android:overScrollMode">never</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/SalmonButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerStyle</item>
```

And a layout:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bodyBg">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="270dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/image_closing_club"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="30dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    ...Here is constraint layout with a big number of views


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So how can I see proper bottom of `NestedScrollView`  above `NavigationBar`?

Actual:

[image: Actual Bottom of NestedScrollView]

Expected:

[image: Expected Result]

I can even see on a preview, that my main container is behind `NavigationBar`

[image: BluePrint]

**EDIT** Looks like this problem appears only from API 28

Comment: Post some screen shots please.

Comment: @aminography added